# The type '...' exists in both 'Util.dll" and 'Util (Silverlight).dll'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight, code-sharing

I'm attempting to follow David Betz' [wonderful advice](http://www.netfxharmonics.com/2008/12/Reusing-NET-Assemblies-in-Silverlight#ReusingDotNetInSilverlightFile) on how to use a library project in both your .NET and Silverlight code. In particular, I'm using his File-Level technique: I have a .NET library project already set up, so I created a Silverlight project, and added links in the latter to the former's files.

Unfortunately, there is a problem. I get compilation errors like crazy, of the form:

The type '...' exists in both 'Util.dll' and 'Util (Silverlight).dll'

In all of my other projects, I only reference one or the other. Neither Util dll has a reference to the other, so I'm not sure why the compiler can see both DLLs from any of the other projects.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the first error in the Output?

Comment: The type or namespace name '...' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm going to fix all of these and see if that helps.

Comment: Argh! It really was this simple :) I just fixed the compilation issues other then this one, and it suddenly stopped complaining. 

I also added to the linked projects Project Dependencies (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8t5a6t(v=VS.80).aspx) on the real projects, and that helped keep the errors more consistent, at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer posted by frank in comments. Porting to answer and community wikiing it in hopes that it'll be accepted as the answer.

**Comment**

> Argh! It really was this simple :) I just fixed the compilation issues other then this one, and it suddenly stopped complaining.
>
> I also added to the linked projects [Project Dependencies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8t5a6t(v=VS.80).aspx) on the real projects, and that helped keep the errors more consistent, at least.

– frank